# API Token returning 401 Unauthorised when its working in URL

Tags: node.js, express, token, superagent

I am making a Multi-Purpose API Service and as I got the token in the URL working perfect and authorising as expected with a 200. I've been having issues with the token not authorising with curl command or superagent, as its always return a 401 error.

auth.js

```js
const { DB } = require('../src/Routes/index.js');
module.exports = function auth(req, res, next) {

  if(!req.query.apiKey) {
    return res.status(401).json({"error": "401 Unauthorized", message: "API Token is missing in the query. You will need to generate a Token and put in the apiKey query."})

  } else {
    let check = DB.filter(k => k).map(i => i.apiToken);
    console.log(check);
    let t = check.some(e => e == req.query.apiKey)

    if(t !== true)
    return res.status(401).json({"error": "401 Unauthorized", message: "The API Key you provided is invalid. Please refer to our Docs () and Generate a Token ()"}); 

    return next();
  } 
}
```

This is the middleware for the token, I am using this in my routers so then the token will authenticate. However, if I remove the `if` statement for checking if an API Token is present. It seem to fix the issue kinda but always authenticates with any key (even ones not saved in the db) and is still not properly fixed.

and an example for requesting endpoint with token on a Discord Command:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const { get } = require("superagent");

exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {

    const { body } = await get(`https://example.com/generators/3000years`)
    .query({ image: message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true, size: 2048 }) })
     .set("Authorization", `Bearer MY_TOKEN`);

   const embed = new MessageEmbed()
     .setTitle(`**3000 Years**`)
     .attachFiles({ attachment: body, name: "3000years.png" })
     .setImage("attachment://3000years.png")
     .setColor(`#ed8a5c`);

   message.channel.send(embed);
            }
```

You can see that if I authorise with Superagent, it will not work and return a `401 Unauthorised` in the console.

I would like to ask why this is doing this and if I did something wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's the output of T if you use console.log? You're using a strict comparison to ensure T is NOT true (type/condition), which is different to `!= true`. I would remove that second in favor of `if(!t)`, but update with the output of console.log(t). What error message to? Key missing or key invalid? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: T returns "true" meaning that the token authentication was successful. Thats only done if I query it in the url or via .query in Superagent. EDIT: Its outputting tokens and still working. But need to test with Superagent.

EDIT2: Still giving unauthorised

Comment: "true" or true? Typeof T =? If its not boolean then that may be the issue, using === is strict comparing type and value. Check that reference I linked in an earlier comment it explains this a lot better than I could in my character limit